# [JDBC Driver]Illegal start index - AWS Redshift

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have an aws redshift procedure and I run the procedure as a batch to create and a 'CALL' command to run this stored procedure. I get an error **'[JDBC Driver]Illegal start index.'** I am using Aginity Pro tool and this tool doesn't give me a detailed error or a specific line where this error might have occurred. I tried looking for this error but couldn't get an answer that would help me understand what would have gone wrong. What does this error mean?

This is the syntax for my stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_something_prc(table_name CHARACTER VARYING)
AS $$
BEGIN
    body(chain of commands that needs to be done, like insert, update etc)
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To call that, I am doing this:

```
CALL test_something_prc('table1');
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what driver and version you’re using? Also, is the error specific to Aginity? Can you run this with another tool?

Comment: Try using the DBeaver community edition, that works for me!